# Building Tensorflow Java Maven dependency for upload in internal repo

Tags: java, maven, tensorflow, bazel

I'm doing an in-house build of Tensorflow with CPU optimizations (AVXx, SSE4.x, etc.), so I can use it in Java micro service, which so far is successful, but I have to manually copy files.
I want to produce a Maven artifact, which will be uploaded to our internal Maven repo. 
I'm trying to compile something of these scripts([ci_build](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/builds/libtensorflow.sh)) and docs([maven](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/maven/README.md), [java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/README.md) ), but I was wondering if there is less hack-ish  way?
So far was able to build maven dependency, containing only Java API jar with:

```
git/tensorflow/tensorflow/java/maven$ mvn install:install-file \
-Dfile=../../../bazel-bin/tensorflow/java/libtensorflow.jar \
-DpomFile=../../../bazel-bin/tensorflow/java/pom.xml
```

The mvn command in the question is executed after building with bazel: `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/java:tensorflow   //tensorflow/java:libtensorflow_jni`

Unfortunately *.so files are missing. I can copy them manually to `tensorflow/tensorflow/java/maven/...`, before executing `mvn install` but I prefer not to do that. :)

Comment: Have you considered using bazel ? IIRC it's the standard way to build tensorflow, and it's possible to build java code with it too.

Comment: The mvn command in the question is executed after building with bazel  bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/java:tensorflow   //tensorflow/java:libtensorflow_jni

Answer (score 1):

Extract from my Docker image for building Tensorflow. After TF has been build produce a Maven artifact:

## Build jar and src jar of Java API and tar archive of the native *.so binaries

```
    RUN bazel build -s -c opt $TF_GCC_FLAGS \
                               //tensorflow/java:libtensorflow.jar \
                               //tensorflow/java:libtensorflow-src.jar \
                               //tensorflow/tools/lib_package:libtensorflow_jni.tar.gz

WORKDIR /tf/tensorflow-${TENSORFLOW_VERSION}/tensorflow/java/maven
```

## Copy binaries to maven folder, so that Maven can build artifacts

```
ENV NATIVE_DIR="/tf/tensorflow-${TENSORFLOW_VERSION}/tensorflow/java/maven/libtensorflow_jni/src/main/resources/org/tensorflow/native/linux-x86_64"
RUN mkdir -p "${NATIVE_DIR}" && \
    tar -zxvf ${TF_ROOT}/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/lib_package/libtensorflow_jni.tar.gz -C ${NATIVE_DIR} && \
    cd libtensorflow && \
    jar -xvf ${TF_ROOT}/bazel-bin/tensorflow/java/libtensorflow-src.jar && \
    rm -rf META-INF
```

## Updated timestamps seem to be required to get Maven to pick up the file.

## Skip PGP signing of the binaries, since we don't have PGP key.

```
RUN touch ${NATIVE_DIR}/* && \
    mvn versions:set -DnewVersion="${TENSORFLOW_VERSION}-cpu-optimized" && \
    mvn package -Dgpg.skip=true

CMD mvn install -Dgpg.skip=true
```